# SSRS , Not clear where I should change my code to get away from the overload IIF parameter problem in my expression

Tags: sql-server, database, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

So I am trying to resolve the case where I have two fields namely 'Success' and 'Fail'. I want to show the value of the 'Success' field as 100 when both fields(Success and Fail) are zero but in case the 'Fail field has a value other than zero but the value of the 'Success' field is still 0, I want success field to show '0' while 'Fail' should show the appropriate value.

For this I have written the below expression with nested iif loops, I am new to SSRS reporting. So any help/suggestions will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

**SSRS Expression:**

```
=iif(Fields!CountAlwaysOnSuccess.Value=0,100,iif(Fields!CountAlwaysOnFail.Value!=0,Fields!Always_On_SLO_Success.Value)) & "%," & Fields!CountAlwaysOnSuccess.Value
```

**This is the error that I am getting for my expression above:**

> The Value expression for the textrun
> ‘Textbox2.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: [BC30516]
> Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'IIf' accepts this
> number of arguments.

Comment: `IIf` expected **three** arguments; your inner `IIf` only has two, a boolean expression and the return value when said boolean expression evaluates to TRUE.

Comment: Oh right ! Thanks for pointing that out. I tried adding the third parameter but now I am getting the below error.                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                    
The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox2.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: [BC30277] Type character '!' does not match declared data type 'Object'.

Comment: use `<>` in SSRS expressions instead of `!=`

Comment: Thanks, @AlanSchofield for your suggestions. Any clue on how I can add the round function here to get the value of the 'Success' / 'Fail' field up to two decimal places when displayed as percentages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `IIF` function takes three parameters:

```
IIF(Condition, ValueWhenTrue, ValueWhenFalse)
```

You say that you want to display:

- `100%` when both `Success` and `Fail` are zero
- `0%, <FailValue>` when `Success` is zero and `Fail` is non-zero

However, your formula displays the `Always_On_SLO_Success` field when `Fail` is non-zero. It looks like we can display these two fields when either `Success` or `Fail` are non-zero, so I don't think you need your second conditional. You probably also need to cast your numeric fields to string. Try something like this:

```
=IIF(Fields!CountAlwaysOnSuccess.Value + Fields!CountAlwaysOnFail.Value = 0, 
    "100%", 
    CStr(Fields!Always_On_SLO_Success.Value) & "%," & CStr(Fields!CountAlwaysOnFail.Value) & "%")
```

Comment: I was able to acheive the desired results by modifying the solution provided by you. This is what I did.                                                                 
           `=IIF(Fields!CountAlwaysOnSuccess.Value +Fields!CountAlwaysOnFail.Value =0, 
    100, Fields!Always_On_SLO_Success.Value) & "%," & Fields!CountAlwaysOnSuccess.Value`